# Command handler loading the files however not running them

Tags: discord.js

Hi (no expert by all means)

Working with discord.js setting up a command handler, I know the files are being loaded however when I am running them they don't work (run).

Start of my index file

```
const { prefix, token }  = require("./settings/config.json");
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const fs = require("fs");
const bot = new Discord.Client();
bot.commands = new Discord.Collection();
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

for (const file of commandFiles) {
  const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
  commandFiles.run(bot, message, args);
  console.log(`${file} loaded!`);
  bot.commands.set(command.name, command);
}
```

One of the files in the commands folder (which is loads but doesn't run):

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client();
let servericon = ('https://i.imgur.com/foKcByT.png');

module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {
  // No Perms Embed
  const noPermsErrEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  .setColor('FF6961')
  .setTitle("**error!**")
  .setDescription("This command can only be used by staff!")
  .setTimestamp()
  .setFooter(message.author.tag + " | Peace Keeper", message.author.displayAvatarURL({dynamic: true, size: 1024}))
  if(!message.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_MESSAGES")) return message.reply(noPermsErrEmbed).then(msg => msg.delete(5000));

  let ancArgs = args.slice(0).join(" ").split('|');
  
  if (args.length >= 3) {
    message.delete().then(() => {
      const ancEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setColor('#ABDFF2')
      .setTitle("** " + ancArgs[0] + " **")
      .setDescription(ancArgs[1])
      .setTimestamp()
      .setThumbnail(servericon)
      .setFooter(message.author.tag + " | Peace Keeper", message.author.displayAvatarURL({dynamic: true, size: 1024}))
      message.channel.send(ancEmbed);
    })
  } else {
    message.delete().catch();
    const ancErrEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setColor('FF6961')
      .setTitle("**error!**")
      .setDescription("use the correct format: !special-anc <title> | <message>")
      .setTimestamp()
      .setFooter(message.author.tag + " | Peace Keeper", message.author.displayAvatarURL({dynamic: true, size: 1024}))
      message.reply(ancErrEmbed).then(msg => msg.delete({timeout: 10000}));
  }
}

module.exports.help = {
  name: "special-anc"
}
```

Comment: Discord.js version 12

Comment: I forgot to mention the error message sorry:

`commandFiles.run(bot, message, args);
                        ^

ReferenceError: message is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\amral\Google Drive\Jordan-Discord-Bot\index.js:10:25)`

Answer (score 0):

It won't run the commands because you used the wrong variable to call the run part:

```
   commandFiles.run(bot, message, args);
```

It should be:

```
   command.run(bot, message, args);
```

commandFiles is just a list of files so it has nothing to do directly with your commands.

However, there's something wrong with your code.
This is your module.exports object (inside the `command` variable):

```js
{
   run: [AsyncFunction],
   help: { name: String }
}
```

When you use this line `bot.commands.set(command.name, command);`, it won't work because there's no `name` property, it should be `help.name`.